# How can I export numerical data in a calculation-favorable format?

Tags: functions, export, number-representation, big-numbers

I am exporting some data into the txt file but since the values exported to this txt file
expresses 10^6 to be *^6, I cannot use these numbers in calculations in other programs..
For instance, when I do,

```
 AA= {-292., -5., -9036., -1.162*10^6, -1.555*10^6, \
     -1.85*10^6, -2.146*10^6, -2.401*10^6, -2.736*10^6, \
     -2.91*10^6}
 Export["C:/data output1.txt", AA]
```

May I ask how I can deal with this problem..?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
Export["data_output1.txt", AA, "CSV"]
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: Or perhaps just `Export["data_output1.csv", AA]`

Comment: Yep, I assumed the OP wanted a `.txt` file

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot!